# Microsoft SSRS: How to make horizontal flowing fill-in text

Tags: reporting-services

Apologies if this has been asked before, I did look around but I'm new to SSRS and I might not know the right keywords to find what I'm looking for.

I am trying to make a new report with a couple of sentences like:

```
The purpose of this report is to determine an academic plan for student __________, by listing all the courses they will take.
```

I would like this to display in my report "just like" a paragraph of text, except that I would like the blank filled in with the student's name.

I understand how to do "basic" textboxes and how to bind values to them.

But how to I get a textbox that knows to expand horizontally until it reaches the end of the line, and then continues on the next line?  If this was HTML (with some binding libraries like Knockout), I'd stick it all in a `<p>`, like:

```
<p>The purpose... <span data-bind="studentName" />, by listing ... </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use placeholders, they will do exactly what you want.

Create a text box with the full sentence, then at the position where you want the student name to appear, right-click on the actual text and choose 'create placeholder'.

Once the placeholder is visible, right-click and choose properties, then just set the value to whatever you want.

The placeholder is like an inline textbox, you can set it to be the contents of a field or an expression, give it it's own formatting etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you need a field in a text box with static text, you'd put the text in quotes and use the **&** to combine them

```
="The purpose of this report is to determine an academic plan for student " & Fields!NAME.Value & " by listing all the courses they will take."
```

Text boxes don't expand horizontally though. The text will take up as much room in the text box as it can and then will make a new line in the text box - expanding vertically.

Comment: This isn't the approach I ended up taking, but it was helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are using BI Studio to do this.
I am assuming that your underlying query just produces one value called FieldName and your data source is called DataSource. The text will wrap to your textbox but you can add in a vbCrLf if you want to force linebreak. Concatenating strings you can use + or &.

In your textbox make a formula and set it to:
="First part of string "+First(Fields!FieldName.value, "DataSource")+" rest of sentence"+vbCrLf+"more string"